# JS - load script more faster in head

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everyone I have this code in the head which basically checks two parameters inside a localStorage and then takes off an alternate stylesheet, but I noticed that it is a bit slow and the second style is loaded after a few seconds after loading page, I would like it to be loaded before the page content appears. Can you help me simplify the code and make it faster for what I need. Thanks so much

```
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/day.css" rel="stylesheet alternate" id="day">
    <link href="/css/night.css" rel="stylesheet alternate" id="night">

    <script src="js/sun.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var Mode;

        var localStorageMode = localStorage.getItem('style-mode');
        if (localStorageMode){
            Mode = localStorageMode;

            if(Mode == 'night'){
                $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
            }else{
                $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
            }

        }else{
            var startEnd = localStorage.getItem('style-mode-start-end');
            if (startEnd){
                startEnd = JSON.parse(startEnd);
                var startAt = normalizeTime(startEnd[0].start),
                    endAt = normalizeTime(startEnd[0].end),
                    now = new Date().getTime();

                if((endAt < now && now > startAt) || (startAt > now && now < endAt)){
                    $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                    $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                }else{
                    $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                    $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                }

            }else{
                var addressCity = '<?php echo $_SESSION["userCity"]; ?>';
                var addressNation = '<?php echo $_SESSION["userNation"]; ?>';
                var addressNationISO = '<?php echo $_SESSION["userNationISO"]; ?>';
                var address = addressCity+" "+addressNation+" "+addressNationISO;

                if(address != ""){
                    $.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q='+address, function(data){
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            var dataLat = data[0].lat,
                                dataLon = data[0].lon;
                            var sunset = new Date().sunset(dataLat, dataLon);
                            var sunrise = new Date().sunrise(dataLat, dataLon);

                            var sunsetHoursMinutes = sunset.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0")+":"+sunset.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
                            var sunriseHoursMinutes = sunrise.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0")+":"+sunrise.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");

                            var arrayStartEnd = [{start: sunsetHoursMinutes, end: sunriseHoursMinutes}];

                            setPZLNModeStartEnd(arrayStartEnd);

                            var startAt = sunsetHoursMinutes,
                                endAt = sunriseHoursMinutes,
                                now = new Date().getTime();

                            if((endAt < now && now > startAt) || (startAt > now && now < endAt)){
                                $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                                $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                            }else{
                                $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                                $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                            }

                        }else{
                            var startAt = normalizeTime("18:00"),
                                endAt = normalizeTime("06:00"),
                                now = new Date().getTime();

                            if((endAt < now && now > startAt) || (startAt > now && now < endAt)){
                                $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                                $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                            }else{
                                $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                                $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }else{
                    var startAt = normalizeTime("18:00"),
                        endAt = normalizeTime("06:00"),
                        now = new Date().getTime();

                    if((endAt < now && now > startAt) || (startAt > now && now < endAt)){
                        $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                        $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                    }else{
                        $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
                        $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is `endAt` always bigger than startAt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the code shorter by group

```
$("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet alternate');
$("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet');
```

Into a function like

```
function toggleDayNight(value) {
  value = !!value; // Parse boolean
  $("#day").attr('rel', 'stylesheet' + (value ? ' alternate' : ''));
  $("#night").attr('rel', 'stylesheet' + (value ? '' : ' alternate'));
}
```

Then group all the code with endAt, startAt into function `checkPeriod`

```
function checkPeriod(startAt, endAt, usingNormalize = true) {
  if (typeof startAt == 'undefined') {
    // Create default value
    startAt = normalizeTime("18:00");
    endAt = normalizeTime("06:00");
  } else if (usingNormalize) {
    startAt = normalizeTime(startAt);
    endAt = normalizeTime(endAt);
  }
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  return (endAt < now && now > startAt) || (startAt > now && now < endAt);
}
```

This function also create default value if nothing supplied to it. 
I'm not sure that it is faster, but it shorter.

This is the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wy9uh1r0/2/

Also if `endAt` always bigger than `startAt`, you can replace

`(endAt < now && now > startAt) || (startAt > now && now < endAt)`

with

`!(startAt <= now && no <= endAt)`

Comment: Thank you! Work but it works but the first time it loads the page, the night style appears even if it is not saved in the localStorage and even if the time slot is that day of the style. If I reload the page I will load the right style. The variable endAt is aletas bigger than startAt

Comment: May I now when the night style active? When `#night` has class `alternate` ?

Comment: as a first call it is always addressed to the #night style but if I reload the page a second time everything returns to normal. I checked the heads but everything is ok .... I don't know where the problem is @VanTho